# Where is the C drive in the WSL?

Tags: command-line, bash, shell, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-10-v1607

Whenever I try to login to `bash` using the Windows Subsystem for Linux, I try to `cd` into `C:\Users\`, but all I get is directory not found.

Where is the `C` drive for the Windows Linux subsystem? Is it isolated?

Comment: For user folder type in, cd /mnt/c/Users  ...to access desktop type in, cd /mnt/c/Users/my-name/Desktop ...case sensitive

Comment: There are some considerations when going to the Windows drive space from WSL. This page has more answers to your question here and other related information. It's a good starting point: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/filesystems

Answer (score 151, accepted):

Taken from [this website](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2016/07/22/fun-with-the-windows-subsystem-for-linux/):

> The WSL has access to your PC’s file system through `/mnt/<drive letter>/` directories (or mount points). For example, your `C:\` and `D:\` root directories in Windows would be available through `/mnt/c/` and `/mnt/d/` respectively in the WSL

Just `cd` into the `/mnt` folder and you'll be fine

Answer (score 37):

#### `/mnt/c` or `/mnt/<drive letter>/`

> you’ll find your local drives mounted under the `/mnt` folder.
> For example, your `C:` drive is mounted under `/mnt/c` <sup>[[msdn](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/faq)]</sup>

The Linux filesystem is a unique tree (there are no `C:\`, `D:\` ...).
The root of this tree is `/` (note `/` not `\`).

All the *units* – partitions, pen drives, removable disks, CD, DVD – will be available when *mounted* on a point of this tree.  Then you will see them as normal directories.

The usual place where the additional partitions are mounted is the `/mnt` directory.
This works under the Windows Linux Subsystem too.

**Note:** Under Linux, you've got to use the slash (`/`) instead of the  backslash (`\`) to separate the directories in a path. And usually a Linux filesystem is case sensitive (`mydir` and `Mydir` are two different things).

Comment: how do you access DVD from WSL? I only see /mnt/c in there

Comment: But this is another question `;-)` (@santiagoarizti). BTW once _mounted_ it should be in `/mnt/d` or similar. (Under pure Linux it may be under `/media/YourUsername/TheLabelNameOfCd` or similar). If you need to mount it before create a directory e.g. `sudo mkdir /mnt/MyDVD`  then mount it with something like `sudo mount -t drvfs D: /mnt/MyDVD` or similar commands...

Answer (score 12):

**Since the days of Windows NT, there has been another way to access drives**. Instead of using a letter, you can bind a drive to a folder in the filesystem. Microsoft calls these *mounted folders*. As far as the end user is concerned, they work just like normal folders do: they happen to reside on another drive, but under most circumstances you don't notice. This can be useful in a number of scenarios, but it turns out to be critical if you happen to have so many drives mounted that you run out of drive letters, but need to add even more: mounted folders are how you can do that.

**In Linux (and Unix, which inspired it), *all* drives work this way**. There is only one filesystem, which starts at the empty path `/` (and is typically bound to a drive), and then you mount your other drives (or, sometimes, other things) using directories inside `/`. These are called *mount points* in Unix terminology (which Linux inherited). For example, user home directories are often in `/home/`*username*, but it's common to make `/home` a mount point for another drive entirely. That way if the drive you boot from fails for some reason, your home directories aren't affected. The users just go to `/home/`*username* like they always do; unless they're responsible for maintaining the machine, they don't have to know or care what drive their home directories are on.

**The WSL tries to imitate Linux, so it does this too. To bridge the gap, it mounts your Windows drives in the folder '/mnt/', using the drive letter as the directory name**. Your C: drive, for example, can also be found at `/mnt/c`, while your D: drive is at `/mnt/d`.