# How can I "open" a file from WSL with the default application?

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Most systems provide an `open` command (alternately known as `start`, `cygstart`, `xdg-open` etc.) which opens a file in the desktop environment's "default" application, whatever that is.

For example, from Powershell when I enter:

```
PS> start form.pdf
```

The document pops open in Edge.

Can Bash-on-Ubuntu-on-Windows do this?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

A recent answer for WSL 2: Just do `wslview slides.pdf`.

This is a part of the [wslu collection](https://github.com/wslutilities/wslu) and was pre-installed in my Ubuntu. Unfortunately, the documentation is a bit sparse.

All the `cmd.exe` variants didn't work for me, because it doesn't want to open inside a path like `\\wsl$\…`

Comment: Nice, and `wslview .` opens the current directory in Windows Explorer.

Comment: This is so good

Comment: Thanks, I've marked this as the accepted answer as WSL2 becomes the more common deployment. NB: On my system, this maps to a fake network share like `\\wsl$\Ubuntu-20.04`, which is on disk as something like `C:\Users\Cheezmeister\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu20.04onWindows_79rhkp1fnegsc\LocalState\rootfs`

Comment: A bit sad that this command does not work under Windows cmd so you can't have a cross-platform (WSL + host OS) solution.

Comment: `wslview` takes between 2–4 seconds to open an application (on my device). `cmd.exe` and `explorer.exe`—when they work—open applications almost immediately. (Can confirm that `cmd.exe` _does not want_ to deal with UNC/network paths.)

Comment: Works for WSL 1 on Windows 10.

Comment: FWIW to future readers, while this method works, it was almost 8x slower than just using the native `cmd.exe /C start` [method](https://superuser.com/a/1252579/103992).  You can check by prepending `time` to your commands, but it is so noticeable you do not even need to.

Comment: `alias open="wslview"`

Comment: wslu can be installed via: `sudo apt install wslu`

Comment: If there are parentheses in the filename, this will die with `CommandNotFoundException`, showing an error message like "`The term <something> is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, script file, or operable program.`"

Comment: @Seldom'Where'sMonica'Needy I don't use Windows anymore, but I would guess it's an escaping issue (parens create sub-shells). So it should work if you put your filename in single quotes.

Answer (score 46):

Since the Windows Linux interop started working you can now call:

```
cmd.exe /C start <file>
```

Comment: Works for me for relative paths, for absolute paths I wrote a script to substitute /mnt/c by c:

`... | sed 's/\/mnt\/\(.\)/\1:/1' | xargs cmd.exe /C start`

Comment: Nice solution. We can also access files on the Linux filesystem using info from https://superuser.com/q/1110974/66714. Something like `cmd.exe /c start "%localappdata%/lxss/$(readlink -f $some_relative_path)"` Now we're cooking with fire!

Comment: If your `cmd` doesn't want to open, see [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1600972/1017330).

Comment: I guess Martijn's answer doesn't work in WSL 2 anymore.

Answer (score 8):

As Martijn noted this is the correct way to execute/open a Windows application/file.

```
cmd.exe /C start <file>
```

I found it very useful to work this into a bash script that I keep in a folder that is in my system path. I name it `start` and do `chmod 0744` to the file to make it executable. The `$*` means it will pass all of the command line arguments you provided to the script to `cmd.exe`.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
cmd.exe /c start "Launching from BASH" "$*"
```

With this command in my system path I can commands like this in Linux that open in Windows:

1. `start FileXYZ.pdf` // Opens the PDF in the default assigned PDF viewer in Windows
2. `start explorer .`  // Opens current WSL folder in the Windows Explorer
3. `start MyApp.exe`   // Launches the Windows application

Comment: The only problem is that this solution does not work with files which have whitespaces in their name.

Comment: @h3nrik Great point. I guess I don't open a lot of files with spaces in Linux. I updated the script it to handle that.

Comment: On Linux filenames with whitespaces are usually handled with backslashes like ```a\ whitespace.pdf```. Starting your script like ```start.sh a\ a.pdf b\ b.pdf``` would not work.

Comment: `explorer.exe .` opens the current path in Windows Explorer

Answer (score 7):

to expand on Martijn's answer, you can put

```
alias start='cmd.exe /C start'
```

in your .bashrc to get expected windows behavior, eg `start .` opens explorer in current dir.

Comment: To access bashrc, you use vi(vim) or nano by simply typing nano ~/.bashrc to edit the file.

Answer (score 6):

This worked much better for me:

```bat
explorer.exe `wslpath -aw <path>`
```

Comment: Normally I use the wslview solution above, but that was not working for opening a file in Notepad. This worked beautifully though!

Comment: Update: also works on Excel files!

Answer (score 3):

The **best and easiest way to open the files with the default application** is using **`explorer.exe`** if you have WSL.

$`explorer.exe <file>`:

$`explorer.exe form.pdf`: that command line uses the windows explorer to **open the file with the default program.**

With `explorer.exe` you can also **open a folder in your WSL with the windows file explorer**, just insted of using a file as parameter you can specify a directory:

$`explorer.exe <directory>`:

$`explorer.exe .`: Opens the file explorer of windows in the current location.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on whether you want to A) launch a linux program inside WSL or B) you want to launch a windows program from a bash shell prompt.

If B) then yes if you install cygwin/bash. For example install [git for windows](https://git-scm.com/download/win) and you have a system running under windows with bash. Then you can just run start, actually it is included as a script:

```
$ cat /usr/bin/start
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Copyright (C) 2014, Alexey Pavlov
#   mailto:alexpux@gmail.com
# This file is part of Minimal SYStem version 2.
#   https://sourceforge.net/p/msys2/wiki/MSYS2%20installation/
# File: start

cmd //c start "${@//&/^&}"
```

If A) then it gets much more difficult especially if you want to launch a linux program to display a .pdf in a GUI window. Note that Windows knows to associate a default application to open a pdf file but WSL doesn't have the information. So even if you did get a [Desktop running under WSL](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/637) you would need to associate a linux GUI app to open the pdf.

*Note to clarify, within WSL you execute linux executables not windows executables:*

```
(WSL):~# file /bin/gzip
/bin/gzip: ELF 64-bit LSB  executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=68cc3c090405cf6d40e97d2ff58085fd26940602, stripped

(WSL):~# file /mnt/c/Program\ Files/Internet\ Explorer/iexplore.exe
 /mnt/c/Program Files/Internet Explorer/iexplore.exe: PE32+ executable (GUI) x86-64, for MS Windows

(WSL):~# /mnt/c/Program\ Files/Internet\ Explorer/iexplore.exe
 bash: /mnt/c/Program Files/Internet Explorer/iexplore.exe: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found that explorer.exe works pretty well at finding the correct resolved path (even of mounted network directories) and launching the default tool. The one gotcha is that you can't have paths in the filename, so you need to create a little helper function/script to launch explorer correctly, e.g.:

```
win() { 
    # get full unsymlinked filename 
    file=`readlink -e $1` 
    dir=$(dirname "$file") 
    base=$(basename "$file") 
    # open item using default windows application 
    (cd "$dir"; explorer.exe "$base")
}
```

**Update:**  Ngo pointed out another script, `wslpath`, that does the path conversion, so you can call explorer.exe directly on the path (after converting).  Then the function above becomes trivial and can easily be made an alias.

Comment: Excellent solution!

Answer (score 1):

`eopen` can open various files (, directories and URI) within WSL.

https://github.com/ko1nksm/eopen-ecd

**Examples**

```
# Open directory with (latest used) Explorer
eopen ~/.config/

# Open directory with new instance of Explorer
eopen -n ~/.config/

# Opens with Windows default application
eopen image.png

# Opens with Windows text editor
eopen -e ~/.bashrc

# Use sudo to edit the unowned file
eopen -e --sudo /etc/hosts

# Opens with Windows default browser
eopen http://google.com

# Open files and directories under Windows
eopen C:/Windows

# Open files and directories under Network shared folder
eopen //server/shared

# Others
eopen mailto:user@example.com   # Mail protocol
eopen calculator:               # Application
eopen shell:Personal            # Shell commands
eopen :MyComputerFolder         # Shorthand for shell:
eopen shell:::{2559a1f8-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0} # CLSID
eopen :                         # Current Explorer location
eopen :/workspace               # Relative path from current Explorer location
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call powershell's `Start-Process` command from within WSL:

`powershell.exe -Command Start-Process file`

For making this also work with absolute paths, you can use the `wslpath -wa` command to translate the path to a windows-path.

`` powershell.exe -Command Start-Process `wslpath -wa /absolute/path/to/file` ``

This has an advantage over the `cmd.exe` solution: for mounted network shares, `wslpath` produces an UNC path like `\\server\share\`. These UNC paths can't be handled by `cmd.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function open {
  cmd.exe /C start "$1" /C bash
}
```

If you want it work in every time just add it to the `.bashrc`:
[enter link description here](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-create-bash-aliases/)

Answer (score 1):

Building on the idea proposed by @zx485 and @Nullcito [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1160419/how-can-i-open-a-file-from-wsl-with-the-default-application/1560219#1560219), you can use this:

```
function start() {
  cmd.exe /C start "$(wslpath -wa $1)" /C bash
}
```

You just need to pass the file and it will convert to the correct Windows path.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `wsl-open`. It opens files with their standard-windows-application and can be downloaded here: https://github.com/4U6U57/wsl-open.

Answer (score 0):

`xdg-open` in Ubuntu 20 could open http URL's but not the local files. Upgrade here: https://github.com/cpbotha/xdg-open-wsl

Answer (score 0):

If you have [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) installed, you can add the following function into your `.bashrc` to use it for fuzzying finding and launching a Windows application for the path you choose:

```bsh
function open() {
  INPUT=$(fzf --preview 'bat --color=always {}' --preview-window=right:50%)
  # Check for path before launching, in case fzf invocation was cancelled
  if [[ -e $INPUT ]] ; then
    cmd.exe /C start $(echo $INPUT)
  fi
}
```

The fzf command references [bat](https://github.com/sharkdp/bat/) as well, for syntax highlighting in the preview pane.  If you do not have `bat` installed, simply replace `'bat --color=always {}'` with `'cat {}'` instead.  The `if` conditional is used to check for an empty path so that `cmd.exe` will not pop-up if you run `fzf` and then cancel out of it without selecting a path.