# How to use start command in bash on Windows

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to use Windows' [`start` command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770297(v=ws.11).aspx) in bash on Ubuntu on Windows (i.e., WSL).
However, I couldn't use it by simply typing `start`:

```
nek@NEK:/mnt/c/Users/Nek$ start test.txt
Command 'start' is available in '/sbin/start'
The command could not be located because '/sbin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
This is most likely caused by the lack of administrative privileges associated with your user account.
start: command not found
```

And I noticed that `start.exe` might not exist.

```
C:\Users\Nek>where start
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
```

Is `start` a builtin command? Can we use `start` in bash?

#### Environment

- Windows 10 build 14393.693 (**Update**: This version is old for executing `.exe` files on bash. I should update Windows build >= 14951, and then follow the answer.)
- Bash on Ubuntu on Windows (bash 4.3.11(1)-release x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, Ubuntu 14.04)

#### Related Links

- ["How can I “open” a file from WSL with the default application?"](https://superuser.com/questions/1160419/how-can-i-open-a-file-from-wsl-with-the-default-application) -- superuser
- ["Interop between Windows and Bash"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/10/19/interop-between-windows-and-bash/) -- Windows Command Line Tools For Developers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In other answers, `cmd.exe` is suggested. However, the *Command Prompt* does not support UNC paths. The Linux file system in WSL2 is represented as UNC paths in Windows.

In this case, the better alternative is ***PowerShell***. Borrowing from Alex G's function, it is re-written as:

```
function start {
  abspath=$(readlink -f "$1");
  wpath=$(/bin/wslpath -w "$abspath");
  powershell.exe -Command Start-Process "$wpath"
}
```

If you have disabled the addition of Windows PATH by adding `[interop] appendWindowsPath = false` to `/etc/wsl.conf`, then use the absolute path gotten by `where powershell.exe`:

```
function start {
  abspath=$(readlink -f "$1");
  wpath=$(/bin/wslpath -w "$abspath");
  /mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0//powershell.exe -Command Start-Process "$wpath"
}
```

Add this to your `.bashrc` to make sure you have it in every session.

**Usage:**

- `start .` - Opens the current directory in Windows File Explorer.
- `start /any/linux/path` - Opens the Linux directory as a UNC path.
- `start /mnt/c/any/windows/path` - Opens the Windows folder as a
  regular path.
- `start` - Forces the PowerShell command to prompt you
  for a path. Type one in, such as `.` or a Windows/UNC path (Linux paths won't work here) or press `Ctrl-C` to cancel.

  - *Perhaps the function can be enhanced to take care of this edge case. I leave that to you as an exercise.*

Comment: This should be marked as the answer.  It's the only one that works reliably.

Answer (score 11):

#### Is start a builtin command?

Yes.

> **Internal commands**
>
> The Windows CMD shell CMD.exe contains a number of 'internal'
>   commands, additional 'external' commands are also supplied as separate
>   executable files. External commands are generally stored in the
>   C:\WINDOWS\System32 folder, this folder is part of the system PATH .
>
> This arrangement means that both internal and external commands are
>   always available no matter what your current directory happens to be.
>
> ASSOC, BREAK, CALL ,CD/CHDIR, CLS, COLOR, COPY, DATE, DEL, DIR, DPATH,
>   ECHO, ENDLOCAL, ERASE, EXIT, FOR, FTYPE, GOTO, IF, KEYS, MD/MKDIR,
>   MKLINK (vista and above), MOVE, PATH, PAUSE, POPD, PROMPT, PUSHD, REM,
>   REN/RENAME, RD/RMDIR, SET, SETLOCAL, SHIFT, START, TIME, TITLE, TYPE,
>   VER, VERIFY, VOL

Source [syntax-internal](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-internal.html)

---

#### Can we use start in bash?

Yes. Start a command shell and run the start command.

Example:

```
cmd.exe /c start "" test.txt
```

If this doesn't work specify the full path as follows:

```
/mnt/c/Windows/system32/cmd.exe /c start "" test.txt
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [cmd](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) - Start a new CMD shell and (optionally) run a command/executable program.
- [start](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) - Start a program, command or batch script (opens in a new window).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the command `cmd` is not found on bash. Am I missing something? (Currently, I doubt whether build version is old.)

Comment: @nekketsuuu You need to add  `.exe` Try using `cmd.exe ...` or specify the full path `/mnt/c/Windows/system32/cmd.exe ...`. Answer updated.

Comment: Maybe system32 -> System32

Comment: @nekketsuuu That shouldn't make a difference, it is the `.exe` that is important. `bash` doesn't know how to execute files if you don't add `.exe` to the command name.

Comment: That is all explained in your second link ...

Comment: In my trial, `/mnt/c/Windows/system32/cmd.exe ...` caused a bash error `No such file or directory`, and `/mnt/c/Windows/System32/cmd.exe ...` caused `cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`. So I'll update Windows Insider Build and try again. Anyway, Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @nekketsuuu Do you need more help? If this answered your question, please don't forget to [accept the answer](http://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: I'll mark this after it succeeds. Please wait for it :-)

Comment: This successfully works on Windows 10 Build 15063.13! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks; I added `alias open='cmd.exe /c start ""' ` to my `.bashrc`.

Comment: **In WSL2,** this only works for directories in the Windows file system. If you run it for any Linux directory, you get the warning `UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.` and sure enough the File Explorer opens up with `C:\Windows`. PowerShell's `Start-Process` supports UNC paths.

Answer (score 3):

The above answer didn't work for me - cmd.exe is expecting a windows path (`C:\this\that`) rather than a linux path.  The following shell function got me up and running:

```
function start {
    abspath=$(readlink -f "$1");
    wpath=$(/bin/wslpath -w "$abspath");
    /c/Windows/System32/cmd.exe /c start "" "$wpath"
}
```

Comment: Wrong syntax - should replace `'$@'` to `"$1"` (Note the double quote. And wslpath can only process one file argument)

Comment: Thanks @JohnnyWong - I've made some edits that get around the quoting problem (not easy to nest double-quotes) and use the correct input var.

Comment: **In WSL2,** it should be `/mnt/c/...`. Unfortunately it only works for folders in the Windows file system, not the ones in Linux (since they are UNC paths). We should use PowerShell's `Start-Process` instead if UNC paths should be supported.