# how to open an office file from WSL

Tags: microsoft-excel, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

My computer: Windows 10 running WSL Ubuntu 18.04.

I want to open a windows app file (e.g. an Excel file) from within a WSL bash prompt.

I have made sure that `excel.exe` is in the `$PATH`.

But when I type:

```
excel.exe /mnt/c/Users/bob/Documents/temp/testfile.xlsx
```

A blank workbook opens, instead of the file I want.

**How do I get excel to open the particular file?**

I have read [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1160419/how-can-i-open-a-file-from-wsl-with-the-default-application) but this returns the error:

```
Invalid switch - "/mnt".
```

I also want to make sure that the BASH window opens this file in the background, (not pausing until the Excel application is closed) so that I can continue to use the BASH prompt.

Comment: Try to use Windows style paths in `cmd /c` command.

Comment: How did you add excel to the WSL path? I can find `EXCEL.EXE` in Office's Program Files, and `./EXCEL.EXE` works when in that dir, but no matter what I add to my path I can't seem to get just `EXCEL.EXE` to work

Comment: Ah, solved that one myself. Created a symbolic link to the exe and dropped it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, after some help from @Biswapriyo and elsewhere, the answer seems to be:

start excel.exe "C:\path/to/file/in/directory.xlsx"

seems random to me, but there you go!

Comment: What about this: `start excel.exe "$(wslpath -w /mnt/c/Users/bob/Documents/temp/testfile.xlsx)"`

Comment: what is the equivalent for word?

Comment: @CarlosRafaelRamirez what is the equivalent for word?

Comment: Should be winword.exe

Answer (score 4):

Copied verbatim from https://superuser.com/a/1600972/362088 :

A recent answer for WSL 2: Just do `wslview /mnt/c/Users/bob/Documents/temp/testfile.xlsx`.

This is a part of the [wslu collection](https://github.com/wslutilities/wslu) and was pre-installed in my Ubuntu.