# windows 10 WSL ubuntu unable to ping anything

Tags: windows, ping, windows-subsystem-for-linux, rails

I cannot ping any website when I am using WSL for windows 10. I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 in WSL.

```
--- google.com ping statistics ---
14 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 38567ms
```

is the result when I try ping google.com I am using windows 10 with IPv4, disabled IPv6. I can ping google.com normally without wsl on my regular command prompt

I'm running Avast internet security and when I ping google from inside the ubuntu/WSL instance this is what I see.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mY0Ks.png): [image]

What do I need to do to enable pinging in WSL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First some background. One should need Windows 10 **Build 17627 or higher** to support Firewall with WSL connections. Here is the section from [WSL release notes](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/WSL/blob/live/WSL/release-notes.md#build-17627-skip-ahead):

> **Build 17627 (Skip Ahead)**
>
> **WSL**
>
> - Windows firewall support for WSL processes. [GH 1852]
>
>   - For example, to allow the WSL python process to listen on any port, use the elevated Windows cmd: `netsh.exe advfirewall firewall
>       add rule name=wsl_python dir=in action=allow
>       program="C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Local\Packages\canonicalgrouplimited.ubuntuonwindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\localstate\rootfs\usr\bin\python2.7"
>       enable=yes`
>   - For additional details on how to add firewall rules, see [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/947709/how-to-use-the-netsh-advfirewall-firewall-context-instead-of-the-netsh)

Next step, find absolute path of the Linux executable that wants Internet connection. The full path can be divided into three parts:

1. `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Packages` -- Path where [Universal Windows Platform apps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Windows_Platform_apps) store user specific files, temporary files etc.
2. `CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu18.04onWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs` -- Path where Ubuntu 18.04 Appx package store Ubuntu usersapce files i.e. `/bin`, `/etc`, `/usr` and others.
3. `\bin\ping` -- Linux `ping` binary.

Hence the whole path is:

```
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu18.04onWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\bin\ping
```

You can use the following PowerShell script to get that path. Just enter `ubuntu` when it asks to enter Distribution name.

```ps
$DistroName=Read-Host "Enter Distribution Name"
$pacakgeName = (Get-AppxPackage *$DistroName*).PackageFamilyName
$appData = [System.Environment]::ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%LocalAppData%")
$InstallDir = $appData + "\Packages\" + $pacakgeName + "\LocalState\rootfs"
echo $InstallDir
Invoke-Item $InstallDir
Read-Host -Prompt "Press any key to continue..."
```

Final step, add the firewall rule. For Windows Firewall, run this command as administrator to add Outbound firewall rule.

```cmd
netsh.exe advfirewall firewall add rule name=wsl_ping dir=out action=allow program=<path_to_ping> enable=yes
```

For Avast Firewall, follow [this instruction](https://support.avast.com/en-ww/article/Antivirus-Firewall-Application-Rules) from Avast Support. Open Settings > General > Exclusion and add the path from previous step.

Canonical answers:

- [Accessing Ubuntu data (like "/etc") from Windows](https://superuser.com/a/1325042/726810)
- [Where is the Linux Subsystem's file system located in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/a/1067403/726810)

Comment: I ran command prompt as administer and ran the netsh.exe command and the result was ok. Then i went into my avast internet security and added the ping path to allow all but I am still getting 100% packet loss when I try to ping google.com on wsl ubuntu

Comment: @user3369850 here is a GitHub discussion you can follow: https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/475