# Complete SSL Ubuntu failure on Windows Subsystem

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-18.04

I am using ubuntu 18.04 on a windows subsystem and SSL has completely stopped working. When running `curl -v https://google.com`, I get `OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to google.com:443`. When running `wget -v --no-check-certificate https://google.com`, I get `Unable to establish SSL connection`. Due to this, pip has stopped working as well, claiming `ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', OSError(0, 'Error'))`. Note that any non-ssl website causes curl and wget to work correctly.

**Attempts to Fix**

- Reinstalled Ubuntu Subsystem
- Upgraded and reinstalled openssl via `sudo apt-get upgrade/remove openssl`
- Disabled ipv6

**System information**

- Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
- OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017

I am completely flummoxed. Any help or suggestions to debug would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please disable any antivirus you are using in windows or at least disable the SSL interception - then try again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [windows 10 WSL ubuntu unable to ping anything](https://superuser.com/questions/1358297/windows-10-wsl-ubuntu-unable-to-ping-anything)

Answer (score 1):

Kaspersky, both free and paid, can block an Ubuntu Subsystem's SSL connections.

Try opening Kaspersky settings. Go to additional. Go to network. Select "Do not scan encrypted connections" under "Encrypted connections scanning".

Based on Steffen's answer (Thanks).

Comment: Works perfectly, good catch