# Open a particular port so WSL can talk to my browser

Tags: windows, networking, firewall, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-firewall

I'm trying to run Jupyter notebooks from WSL (Windows Subsystem For Linux). The default port it uses is localhost:8888

However if I try to reach that in my browser, nothing happens.

If I start Jupyter with `jupyter notebook --port 8080`, I can connect with localhost:8080 with no problems.

So I think this is a firewall problem. I am running Windows Defender but am pretty clueless with it. I tried setting an Incoming Rule to allow port 8888, following the instructions [here](https://www.tomshardware.com/news/how-to-open-firewall-ports-in-windows-10,36451.html) but it didn't help. Then I tried adding an Outgoing Rule as well, but that didn't help either.

I'm probably doing something very simple wrong.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First, let have some prior knowledge about how to get WSL distribution binary path.
See any of these Q&A from SuperUser:

- [How to access linux/Ubuntu files from Windows 10 WSL?](https://superuser.com/questions/1110974/)
- [Accessing Ubuntu data (like “/etc”) from Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/1324632/)
- [Where is the Linux Subsystem's filesystem located in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1067373/)

After [installing jupyter notebook](https://jupyter.org/install) in WSL, resolve the full path of python binary.
Get the distribution installed path from previous answer and append these ones:

- Python2: `\rootfs\usr\bin\python2.7`
- Python3: `\rootfs\usr\bin\python3.5`

The full path will be like this:

```
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu18.04onWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\usr\bin\python3.5
```

Too long, isn't it? Now [allow it in Windows Firewall](https://www.google.com/search?q=allow+a+program+in+Windows+Firewall). It is possible with
Windows Firewall Management Console (`wf.msc`). Here `netsh` command is used.
Run this command as administrator:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule Name=Python Program="put-the-path-here" LocalPort=8888 Action=allow Dir=Out
```

Or with PowerShell:

```
New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Python" -Name "Python" -Direction Outbound -Program "put-the-path-here" LocalPort 8888 -Action Allow
```

This will allow port 8888 for that python binary. If the Windows side browser
is also firewall-ed then allow it to accept the connection. For further details,
see [netsh](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/netsh/netsh-contexts) and [New-NetFirewallRule](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netsecurity/new-netfirewallrule) command syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions... unfortunately this doesn't work for me. The `-LocalPort 8888` part returns an error saying you couldn't set this without a protocol, so I set the Protocol to TCP. Also tried setting it (inbound and outbound) for `/home/me/anaconda3/bin/python3.7` which is the version I suspect Jupyter uses. Turned on firewall logging, but don't see any events even when I connect to 8080... so maybe it's not a firewall issue after all?