# WSL & Ubuntu, how to move the init file

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I deployed a dev environment on wsl and I'm so excited about it. My only problem is the existence of an `init` file in the root path of the system.

[image: root subdirectories]

For one of my clients, I need to have an `/init` directory, **this is a constraint that cannot be changed.**

Needless to say, this renders my exciting and newly found wsl dev environment unusable for this project.

Is there a way to change the path of the wsl `init` file?

Comment: Does the directory have to be called exactly `/init`? Can you change the name of the directory at least?

Comment: @Fanatique Unfortunately no, as I mentioned it is a constraint that cannot be changed.

Comment: FYI, WSL isn't the first system to reserve this path – the Linux kernel has used `/init` as the _initramfs_ main executable's path since 2005. Creating a custom directory there was already a somewhat bad choice.

Comment: @grawity I agree, but it was not my choice unfortunately and I have to work with it as is. My client is a big one (Very difficult to make change occur in their processes), and this directory is key to the project.

Comment: @Biswapriyo, thank you for the warning. Will be glad to read your response :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Late to answer; the project originally mentioned is almost certainly over; and no one else is likely to ever have this need again.  But oh well, here goes ...

Create a chroot jail. Do the following as root:

- Create a location for the chroot:  `sudo mkdir /newroot; cd /newroot`
- Recreate/bindmount all of the necessary directories inside `newroot`:

  - `mkdir usr; mount --bind /usr usr`
  - `mkdir etc; mount --bind /etc etc`
  - `mkdir root`
  - `mkdir -p /home/user; mount --bind /home/user home/user` (substitute the default username for the WSl instance).
  - `mkdir var; mount --bind /var var`
  - `mkdir dev; mount --bind /dev dev`
  - And so on for any other required directories.
- Pay attention to the root directory symlinks in your distribution.  For instance, at least Ubuntu would also require:

  - `ln -s usr/lib lib`
  - `ln -s usr/lib32 lib32`
  - and so on ...
- `mount -t proc none proc`
- `mkdir init` (The customer required init *directory* rather than the "real" root init *file*)

---

Now, to launch the wsl session, set up a shortcut for `wsl -u root -e sh -c "cd /newroot; exec /usr/sbin/chroot /newroot/" su - username`.  Substitute the default `username` of course.

This will launch the user into a chroot jail with just the directory structure you have selected, which obviously does not include the `init` file, but your `init` directory instead.

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr: The `/init` file can not be removed from a **running** WSL distribution.
Because the subsystem is using that file and all processes in that running WSL
distribution are forked from it.

- So, what we can do? The file is **locked** by the subsystem while running that
  distribution. The workaround is to wait or to terminate that running distribution.
  Use `wsl.exe --terminate Distro` command where `Distro` is the name of running
  WSL distribution which you want to terminate. Go to the folder where the
  distribution is installed, follow [this](https://superuser.com/a/1067403/726810) or [this](https://superuser.com/a/1325042/726810). Delete the `init` file.
- Or, if you want to make a tarball of the whole WSL distribution then there is
  no need to terminate the running distribution. Create tarball and exclude init:

```
cd /
tar -cpf backup.tar --exclude=/backup.tar --exclude=/init --xattrs --one-file-system /
```

Check all the commandline options before running this command. Preserving file
permission is must.

- Where does the init file comes from? The init file is created by Microsoft
  WSL developers and **not similar** with systemd, sysVinit or other traditional
  GNU/Linux init systems. The actual file is `System32\lxss\tools\init`.
  When a distribution is launched the Linux Subsystem Manager Service (LXSS)
  copies that file in the rootfs folder (with `CopyFileW()` Win32 API). For [WSL2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-install)
  first the `\tools` folder is mounted with 9p protocol then used as above.

Comment: Even when I delete it, as soon as I start wsl again the init will show up once more. So how to liberate the name `init` in the root of the folder?? When I create a directory `/init` in the root folder via windows, and I try to start wsl, it just says `Access denied`

Comment: As I mentioned before LxssManager service copies it everytime after WSL distribution is launched. So you can't remove it if the distro is running.

Comment: Then I'm not sure what you suggest I do, If I can't remove it while the distro is running. Then I can't remove it at all? I must be misunderstanding something

Comment: So what is the purpose of removing the `init` file? or "tarballing" the whole wsl distro?

Comment: @Aetos The answer doesn't suggest that init can be removed entirely. It requires for WSL and that's how it works. As grawity said, the directory name isn't a good choice.

Comment: thank you for the answer :) I understand better now. I agree the directory name is a horrible choice, but I can't change it.